# Need two different aligns in one line using reportlab

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm creating a table oriented PDF and have the first row repeating for each page. I want this row to have a centered title string and then a right-aligned string with the date (all on the same line, to save vertical space). I thought that this would be stunningly common but I can't find an example of this anywhere. I used two para tags back to back in the most simplistic conception of this and reportlab ends up using the last alignment given only. This tag string would then be used in a Paragraph which then goes into the table cell. So, my question is how can I achieve this two alignment scenario on one line in reportlab? Or, can I alternatively use two Paragraphs back-to-back (with custom styles)?

```
title_pdf = "<para align=center fontSize=14>{}</para><para align=right fontSize=11>{}</para>".format("PAGE TITLE","01/01/2021")
row_ary[0] = [Paragraph(title_pdf,style=styles["Normal"])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table could be separated from the page header I would solve it by using the page template class that includes a property that is called `onPage` (BaseDocTemplate) and `onFirstPage,` and `onLaterPages` (SimpleDocTemplate). Some of it is mentioned on page 70 in the user guide Version 3.5.36

It can be a bit tricky to get it to work so I include some code below to start with.

```
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, landscape
from reportlab.platypus import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib import colors

def func(canvas, doc):
    canvas.saveState()

    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
    (width, height) = landscape(A4)
    canvas.drawCentredString(width / 2.0, height - 1.2 * cm, "PAGE TITLE")
    canvas.drawRightString(width - 1 * cm, height - 1.2 * cm, "01/01/2021")

    canvas.restoreState()
    return func

def create_pdf():
    story = []
    data = [['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4', 'Data5', 'Data6', 'Data7', 'Data8', 'Data9', 'Data10'],
            ['0.2', '-0.1', '0', '0', '-0.5', '0.6','0.2', '-0.1', '0', '0']]*200

    colwidths = (70)
    rowheights = (12)

    t = Table(data, colwidths, rowheights)

    GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
        [('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 5),
         ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
         ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
         ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
         ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
         ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
         ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 2),
         ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica'),
         ('SIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8),
         ('LEADING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8.2),
         ]
    )

    t.setStyle(GRID_STYLE)
    story.append(t)

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('mydoc.pdf', pagesize=landscape(A4), topMargin=50)
    doc.build(story, onFirstPage=func, onLaterPages=func)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_pdf()  # Printing the pdf
```

[image: example output]

Comment: I ran your code and its not quite fitting the bill, but hopefully you can fix. What I'm looking for is a centered "PAGE TITLE", for example, and right-aligned date string off to the right -- all on one line. Sure, it can be in a page header as you've done. Can you swing that?

Comment: Take a look on the amended version, would that be a better fit?

Answer (score 2):

You could try that with a three-columned table and let the first column empty. Set the style with `TableStyle`:

```
from reportlab.platypus import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.platypus.paragraph import Paragraph

title = "PAGE TITLE"
date = "01/01/2021"

table = Table([("", Paragraph(f"{title}"), Paragraph(f"{date}"))])
style = TableStyle([("ALIGN", (1, 0), (1, 0), "CENTER"),  # Select second table col
                    ("ALIGN", (-1, -1), (-1, -1), "RIGHT")])  # Select last table col

table.setStyle(style)
```